# flatten JSON dataframe in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have made an API request and I am receiving the JSON in the nested format below (along with what I expected).

I dont often have to flatten JSON data & when I do, I just use Json_normalize.
I have tried to use json_normalize, but it hasnt had any effect this time.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Just to clarify, once I have made the request the json data is going into a dataframe. The fields should become columns.
The end result is table that has the columns: id, field1, field 2 etc.

```
#ACTUAL
[
    {
        "id": 1000,
        "tableName": {
            "": {
                "field1": null,
                "field2": null,
            }
        }
    },
{
        "id": 1001,
        "tableNameTwo": {
            "": {
                "field1": null,
                "field2": null,
            }
        }
    }

]


#EXPECTED
[
    {
         "id": 1000,
         "field1": null,
         "field2": null,
    },
{
         "id": 1001,
         "field1": null,
         "field1": null,
    },
...
]
```

Comment: `            "": {
                "field": null,
                "field": null,
                "field": null,
                "field": null,
                "field": null,
                "field": null,
                "field": null,
                "field": null,
                "field": null
            }`
This is pretty weird json. I would say every field should have it's own field name. Especially when json groups map to dictionaries in python. Where duplicated keys are removed.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified that I have anonymised the data. They do have their own field names. The data coming through is fine. Its purely the nesting that is the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED**: Below code can work for you.

**Note**: I have modified your input data from `null` to `None`

```
list = [
    {
        "id": 1000,
        "tableName": {
            "": {
                "field1": None,
                "field2": None,
            }
        }
    },
{
        "id": 1001,
        "tableNameTwo": {
            "": {
                "field1": None,
                "field2": None,
            }
        }
    }

]

flatList = []
for i in list:
    tempDict = {}
    for key, value in i.items():
        if key.startswith('table'):
            for m, n in value[''].items():
                tempDict.update({m: n})
        else:
            tempDict.update({key:value})

    flatList.append(tempDict)

print(flatList)
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    'id': 1000,
    'field1': None,
    'field2': None
  },
  {
    'id': 1001,
    'field1': None,
    'field2': None
  }
]
```

if there are any flaws in the code, **contributors** please add a comment and the answer can be updated.

Comment: When i run this snippet it gives me this error: "Exception: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'"

Comment: @datadatadata, i have updated the code with your updated question, it is working for me, do let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

**It is almost always bad practice to flat a json response**, think for example if there is keys duplication in nested object (most of the time the nested object got his own id), how can you solve this conflict?

However if this question is not for production use, and just doing some homework etc. You can use the following code. I tested it on your example:

```
map = [
    {
        "id": 1000,
        "tablename": {
            "": {
                "field1": None,
                "field2": None,
                "field3": None,
                "field4": None,
                "field5": None,
                "field6": None,
                "field7": None,
                "field8": None,
                "field9": None
            }
        }
    }
]
new_map = {}


def flat_json_object(obj):
    for k, v in obj.items():
        if type(v) is dict:
            flat_json_object(v)
        else:
            new_map[k] = v


def flat_json_array(array):
    for obj in array:
        flat_json_object(obj)


flat_json_array(map)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the following:

```py
import pandas as pd

your_list = [
    {
        "id": 1000,
        "tablename": {
            "tableZero": {
                "field0": None,
                "field1": None,
                "field2": None,
            }
        }
    }
]

df = pd.json_normalize(your_list, sep='_')

print(df.to_dict(orient='records')[0])
```

This will output the following dict.

```
your_result = {
    "id": 1000,
    "tablename_tableZero_field0": None,
    "tablename_tableZero_field1": None,
    "tablename_tableZero_field2": None,
}
```

Comment: That's brilliant, thank you for the help. when i test it with an isolated sample set it works perfectly. But when i incorporate it into my Get dataframe req. it give me this error: Exception: IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Yeah that's because `pandas.DataFrame.get` is going to return you a Pandas Series instead of a list. What you can do is the following: `option_with_get_input = input_df.get("jsonColumn").tolist()` or
`option_to_list_input = input_df["jsonColumn"].to_list()`.
Just put one of those options into the `json_normalize` method and everything should work fine. Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for helping. i am getting this error now Exception: KeyError: "None of [Index(['field1', 'field2'...]) are in the [columns]"

Comment: Maybe you can share more code so I can replicate the error message on my local.